# How to mock a methods in the same class under test?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq, automoq

I am using `Moq` v4.13 and `C#`.
I am trying to test method `MethodA` on the interface of `MyClass : IMyInterface`.
`MethodA` has invocations on methods of another interface (`IAnother`) and I have set up those. These seem to be setup fine.

`MethodA` also  invokes `MethodB` (also on `IMyInterface`) and `MethodC` (public, but not on `IMyInterface`) in `MyClass`.

I have set up `MethodB` but while testing, it seems like actual code of `MethodB` is invoked.

As for `MethodC`, I am not sure how to set that up.

```cs
public interface MyInterface 
{
    int MethodA();
    int MethodB();
}
```

```cs
public class MyClass : MyInterface 
{
    public MyClass(IAnother b) {...}
    
    public int MethodB(){...}
    public int MethodC(){...}

    public int MethodA()
    {
        ...
        var x = b.MethodX();
        ...
        var a = MethodB();
        ...
        var b = MethodC()

        return a + b + x;
    }
}
```

```cs
public MyInterfaceHarness
{
   Mock<IAnother> _anotherMock;

   public MyInterfaceHarness() 
   {
       _anotherMock = new Mock<IAnother>();
       Mocker = new AutoMocker();
   }

   public AutoMocker Mocker {get;}
   
   public MyClass MethodAHarness()
   {
       Mocker.Use(_anotherMock)  // Mocker is Automocker
       _anotherMock.Setup(m => m.MethodX()).Returns(5); // this seems to be setup fine

      //here I want to setup invocations to MethodB and MethodC
      ....

      Mocker.CreateInstance<MyClass>();
   }
}
```

```cs
[TestFixture]
public MyInterfaceTest 
{
    private  MyInterfaceHarness _harness;
    private AutoMocker _mocker;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
       _harness = new MyInterfaceHarness();
       _mocker = _harness.Mocker();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Should_Test_MethodA()
    {
        var mi = _harness.MethodAHarness();

        // use _mocker to setup other invocations that need verify            
        ...

        var i = mi.MethodA();
       
       //asserts
       ...
        
    }
}
```

Comment: @Anand Please try to provide valid C# code. For example in C# you can't specify the visibility of an interface method.

Comment: @Anand By the way why do you want to mock out `MethodB` and `MethodC`? Your **System Under Test** is your `MyClass`, not your `MethodA`. You should mock only dependencies, not some parts of the SUT itself.

Comment: @PeterCsala I have fixed the methods defined in the interface. I am new to mocking so I thought without setup of MethodB and MethodC, I would not get a meaningful value to assert.

Comment: @Anand As I said you don't have to mock `MethodB` and `MethodC`. They are part of your Unit so they are not dependencies. You can and should mock `MethodX`. Even though your assertion might look a bit silly it should not bother you. Your simplified example could be verified that easily.

Comment: Do you have any further question?

Comment: No further question, thanks so much @PeterCsala